# double d = 4 / 5 / 6; why the output of this expression is 0?

Tags: java, operators

In my netbeans I had written the following code :

```
package practicejava;

public class Query {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double d = 4 / 5 / 6;
        System.out.println(d);
    }
}
```

Here I was expecting the output to be 0.13333333,
but when I run the program it prints 0.

What is the reason of printing 0?

Comment: you are dividing `int`s , so the result is `int`

Comment: double d = 4.0 / 5.0 / 6.0;